# input date and attribute "max" on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm trying to use the `max` attribute of the `input[type=date]` of HTML5.
My problem is that the `max` attribute doesn't work on the last Chrome stable, even if everywhere is written that it's supported... (http://html5test.com/compare/feature/form-date-min.html)

For example, at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp there is a demo, which should work on Chrome, but instead it does not work.

Even trying on JSFiddle, with this simple example:

```
<input type="date" max="2014-04-09">
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/E5kcM/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Thou shalt not use W3Scools](http://www.w3fools.com/).

Comment: Yes I know, was just an example. It's written everywhere, not just there.

Comment: It partly works, if you open the popup calendar you are not able to select a date later than the `max` value.

Comment: I see, thanks... But with the arrows or with keyboard you can...

Comment: The purpose of max attribute is NOT to restrict UI, but to ask a browser to check validity.rangeOverflow error.

Comment: No this is not true, if it was like you say it would not work even in the date picker. Please don't provide **wrong** replies. Thanks!